# Enum to Dropdown in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I have a `nullable` `enum` defined for a person title and used in a person model.

> ```
> public enum Titles
> {
>     Mr=0,
>     Mrs=1,
>     Miss=2,
>     Dr=3
> }
> ```

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please supply the title.")]
[Display(Name = "Title")]
public Titles Title { get; set; }
```

When I add this property into a create or edit view using the HTML Helper

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Title)
```

the control renders as expected with the enum values within it.

However, when I choose to edit an existing person, the title `enum` doesn't show the current title. It shows an empty entry at the top of the `DropDownList`.

However, if I remove the `nullable`, it always shows the first item in the `enum`.

Any ideas how I get the `DropDownList` to display the correctly chosen `enum` item for the person I am editing?

Many thanks,

Jason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try naming your Title property something else, Title seems to be a some sort of reserved keyword.

Comment: I find that really hard to believe.

Answer (score 8):

I just made a simple test.

You mentioned that you have a `nullable` Enum, but for that you need `public Titles? Title { get; set; }`

and using this Model:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(ErrorMessage = "Please supply the title.")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Display(Name = "Title")]
    public Title? Title { get; set; }
}
public enum Title
{
    Mr = 0,
    Mrs = 1,
    Miss = 2,
    Dr = 3
}
```

with this `ActionResult`

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    var model = new List<Models.TestViewModel>();

    model.Add(new TestViewModel() { Title = Title.Miss });
    model.Add(new TestViewModel() { Title = Title.Mrs });
    model.Add(new TestViewModel() { Title = null });

    return View(model);
}
```

and using a simple HTML

```
@model List<Models.TestViewModel>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
    @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.Count; i++)
    {
        var title = Model[i-1];
        <div>
            <h2>Model @i</h2>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => title.Title)
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => title.Title)
            @Html.EditorFor(x => title.Title)
        </div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

I get this as result:

[image]

Which is exactly what to expect... are you missing something from my example?

Comment: Many thanks for the example. However, changing the enum and property sort things out.